# What is the equivalent format string of DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, datetimeformatter

Do we know if there is an equivalent format string that outputs the same result as `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`?

i.e.

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

would output the same

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way was that incorrect?

Comment: @Andreas I could get mostly the front parts right with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" but the last bits I don't know how.

Comment: `pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX"`, but that is fixed at 7 fractional seconds. You can't get dynamic number of fractional seconds with a pattern.

Comment: @Andreas yes, the dynamic precision of ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME mainly why I couldn't get it right. Feel free to answer this question with a "No".

Comment: @Andreas can you explain why you need three X's? I don't understand this from the documentation. Why does one X not work here? Thanks - appreciate this is an old question but thought the context here warranted just a comment rather than a whole new question.

Comment: @adrem7 That is because 1, 2, or 4 X's is the offset *without* colon, and 3, or 5 X's is the offset **with** colon (e.g. `-0500` vs `-05:00`).

Comment: @Andreas thanks for responding. To clarify, are 1, 2 and 4 X’s interchangeable? i.e. they all mean the same? Are 3 and 5 also interchangeable? So in your response above you just chose the shortest possible correct amount of X’s?

Comment: @adrem7 For parsing, correct, they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No, this is not possible

On request: Yes, we know that there is no equivalent format pattern string of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` omits the seconds and/or nano of second if they are zero. If the nanos are non-zero “As many digits will be output as required.” There is no pattern letter or combination of pattern letters that will give you the same behaviour.

Deep inside `DateTimeFormatter`, `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` uses an `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`, which in turn is defined in this way:

```
    ISO_LOCAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, null);
```

Which is the way to obtain the dynamic behaviour: using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `optionalStart` and `appendFraction` methods.

As an aside, you don’t want to copy the behaviour of `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` exactly. You will want to use the built-in formatter.

Comment: Thanks for showing the behind the scene code as well!

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")));
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

2018-10-03T07:24:14.772+03:00 
2018-10-03T07:24:14.772+03:00
```

Though it will not always produce the same result because ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME prints fraction of second with different length depending on nanos value, while .SSS has fixed lengh = 3

```
     ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ZoneId.systemDefault());
     System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")));
     System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));   

     2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
     2001-01-01T00:00:00.000000001+02:00
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is right about 90% but not when the milli second has trailing zeros.

Comment: So if you believe there is no pattern that fully mimics ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME, feel free to answer "No" and I can accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev Can you explain why you need three X's? I don't understand this from the documentation. Why does one X not work here? Thanks - appreciate this is an old question but thought the context here warranted just a comment rather than a whole new question.