# DateTimeFormatter equivalent to String.format("%tT", value)

Tags: java, java-time

How could I obtain an `DateTimeFormatter` instance that formats exactly as `String.format("%tT", (LocalTime) value)`?

Preferably some static constant.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the available patterns for [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (which backs `String#format`) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)?

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619353/what-is-the-equivalent-format-string-of-datetimeformatter-iso-offset-date-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%tT` resolves to `%tH:%tM:%tS` as per [`Formatter` Date/Time Conversions javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt).

Equivalent would be `HH:mm:ss` pattern as per [`DateTimeFormatter` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
LocalTime d = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(String.format("%tT", d));
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(d));
```

will both print `17:02:41`.