# Java date time format pattern for ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

I'm after the date time format pattern for `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

```
2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00
```

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` is valid for `2019-09-30T10:05:16+1000` but I need the colon in the zone offset

If this is not possible, I'll need a regular expression.

Comment: Semicolon is ISO timezone, try using X instead of Z, see here https://dzone.com/articles/java-simpledateformat-guide

Comment: Does this answer your question, in whole or in part? [What is the equivalent format string of DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619353/what-is-the-equivalent-format-string-of-datetimeformatter-iso-offset-date-time)

Answer (score 3):

You need `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` here.

```
String str = "2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
OffsetDateTime datetime = OffsetDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` prints and parses strings with and without seconds and with and without fraction of second, the latter up to 9 decimals.

If you only need the pattern for the variant of the format given in your question, with seconds and without fraction of second, the answer by MC Emperor is exactly what you need.

If you need the full flexibility of `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, then there is no pattern that can give you that. Then you will need to go the regular expression way. Which in turn can hardly give you as strict a validation as the formatter. And the regular expression may still grow complicated and very hard to read.

**Link:** [My answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624998/5772882) with a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ` or `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        // Default format i.e. OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")));
        System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00
2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00
2019-09-30T10:05:16+10:00
```